# Using date ranges in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I access SQL and the database through an `ODBC` connection via `Excel`. This way I can create refresh-able reports. I use a `?` when using the date `between` condition so that I can use this report often with different date ranges.

The issue is, when I use `OR` conditions I end up having to put in the date range 4 times, or entering 8 different dates. Is there someway to simplify the below, so that I don't have to enter in the date as many times?

```
 Select CFF2X AS TYPE, Count(*) AS COUNT
 FROM  ZBP602F.SIH 
 JOIN ZBP602UF.NRCMCVL1 ON SICUST=CUSTX 
 WHERE SIINVD BETWEEN ? AND ? AND SICOMP IN (01, 03, 06) and SITOT <> 0 and CFF2X <> (' ') AND      IHOCLS IN (004, 800, 007, 100, 008, 102, 104, 140, 105, 110, 111,109) 
 OR  SIINVD BETWEEN ? AND ? AND SICOMP IN (01, 03, 06)  and SITOT <> 0 and CFF2X = (' ') AND   IHOCLS IN (004, 800, 007, 008, 100, 102, 104, 140, 105, 110, 111) 
 OR  SIINVD BETWEEN ? AND ? AND SICOMP IN (01, 03, 06) and SITOT <> 0 AND IHOCLS IN (114) and   SIPAY in ('A', 'E')
 OR SIINVD BETWEEN ? AND ? AND SICOMP IN (01, 03, 06) and SITOT <> 0 AND IHOCLS IN (114) and  SIPAY = 'B' and CFF2X <> (' ')
 Group by CFF2X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE SIINVD BETWEEN ? AND ? AND SICOMP IN (01, 03, 06) AND SITOT <> 0
AND (
        (CFF2X <> ' ' AND
         IHOCLS IN (004, 800, 007, 100, 008, 102, 104, 140, 105, 110, 111,109)
        )
     OR (CFF2X = ' ' AND 
         IHOCLS IN (004, 800, 007, 008, 100, 102, 104, 140, 105, 110, 111)
        )
     OR (IHOCLS = 114 and SIPAY in ('A', 'E'))
     OR (IHOCLS = 114 and SIPAY = 'B' and CFF2X <> ' ')
)
```

You're simply putting the unchanging items in once and then putting the changing bits in as a couple of OR statements. The process of simplifying boolean logic like this is called Logic Reduction (think Karnaugh maps). There are additional optimization you can perform here as well.

Comment: Fantastic, it worked! Thanks so much! I learned a little bit about that in School, but I haven't tried it yet in a real world work situation like today. Great to know!

Comment: How do I do that ? :P

Comment: There should be a check mark under the vote (up/down) buttons to the left of the answer. When you click it, it should fill in. <http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers>

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using some parentheses to prevent the repetitiveness.

If you change the WHERE to something like:

```
WHERE (SIINVD BETWEEN ? AND ? AND SICOMP IN (01, 03, 06) and SITOT <> 0) AND
  (
    (CFF2X <> (' ') AND IHOCLS IN (004, 800, 007, 100, 008, 102, 104, 140, 105, 110, 111,109)) OR
    (CFF2X = (' ') AND IHOCLS IN (004, 800, 007, 008, 100, 102, 104, 140, 105, 110, 111)) OR
    (IHOCLS IN (114) and SIPAY in ('A', 'E')) OR
    (IHOCLS IN (114) and  SIPAY = 'B' and CFF2X <> (' '))
  )
;
```

This will check the SIINVD, SICOMP, and SITOT for all records first being that it is the same query for all.  Then the 4 different cases will be matched.  The current query as you have it may not actually do what you think because of the lack of parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you as well very much for the quick help.

Comment: @SQUISH if this answer solves your problem then don't just go away read [**Accepting Answers: How does it work?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: I see, I can only accept one answer, even if multiple are great answers :(..sorry Jeff.